# Jquery $.each sincrono

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um GRID em uma tela onde, cada linha tem um botão que chama um método javascript passando alguns valores. Nesse método, são é feito uma chamada via `getJSON`.

O problema é que mesmo nessa chamada, especificando `async: false`, o `$.each` não espera para rodar a próxima linha.

Segue o código do `$.each`:

```
console.log('start');
$('#btn_sugerir_todos').click(function(){

    $('.btnSugerir').each(function(index, value) {
        var def = new $.Deferred();
        var id        = $('#' + value.id).attr('data-id');
        var ordcol_id = $('#' + value.id).attr('data-ordcol_id');
        var data      = $('#' + value.id).attr('data-data');
        var hora      = $('#' + value.id).attr('data-hora');
        var cubagem   = $('#' + value.id).attr('data-cubagem');
        var fatexp_id = $('#' + value.id).attr('data-fatexp_id');
        console.log(id);

        sugerirVeiculo(jQPlanejador, id, ordcol_id, data, hora, cubagem, fatexp_id, false);
    });
    console.log('Fim');
});
```

Todos os `console.log()` estão instantâneos no processamento, mas o real resultado da função `sugerirVeiculo()` não está.

Alguem sabe como forço para esperar o resultado linha a linha?

Comment: Onde está a parte assíncrona? é o `sugerirVeiculo`? e onde usas esse `def` e para quê?

Comment: O `def` pode ignorar, não faz nada. Foi de uma tentativa minha de resolver o problema.

Comment: Dentro do `sugerirVeiculo`, eu uso `getJSON`. Eu defini ele com `async: false` mas mesmo assim, está assíncrona.

Comment: Podes mostrar o código desse `sugerirVeiculo` para perceber melhor o que é preciso?